# При компиляции sсss файла в не пустой css файл стираются прошлые настройки

Tags: css, sass, scss

У меня есть файл `css` в котором содержаться все настройки стилей сайта. Я добавил новую страницу на сайт, задал ей настройки в отдельном `scss` файле(получается что у меня настройки каждой страницы в разных `scss` файлах, а `css` файл один, основной), компилирую в `cmd` от `Ruby` и в итоге в `css` файл заносятся только последние настройки(настройки с новой страницы), а все остальные пропадают. Подскажите, как сделать так, что бы при компиляции настройки просто добавлялись в `css` файл, а не перезаписывались?

Я пишу `sass --watch scss/layout/_login.scss:css/style.css` в командной строке.
(`_login.scss` - новый файл, а `style.css` - файл со всеми `css` настройками)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что вы пишите, то он и делает. Вы предыдущий файл никак не используете, конвертируете только новый.
Сделайте ещё один файл, в котором будут подключаться нужные scss-файлы в нужном порядке, и конвертируйте только его.

https://sass-scss.ru/documentation/pravila_i_direktivi/direktiva_import.html